# Emacs: any good guide about creating syntax highlighting for custom language?

Tags: emacs

Does anyone knows a good guide on how to create a syntax highlighting for custom language in emacs?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here are two detailed step-by-step tutorials that should explain everything you need.

- [EmacsLanguageModeCreationTutorial](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial)
- [Elisp: Write a Major Mode for Syntax Coloring](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_syntax_coloring.html)